# Why we say "save file" and not "keep/preserve file"

Tags: linguistics, etymology

Why do we say *save the file/image* instead of *keep/preserve the file/image*? Is it because the original meaning was to save (rescue) the object from being lost?

Answer (score 7):

As always with etymologies of computer related terms I have turned to the jargon file.

Now, though it does not have a mention of the term specifically, it does describe following (you can read only the highlighted part):

> :*Conway's Law*: prov.
>
> The  rule  that the organization of the software and the organization    of  the  software  team will be congruent; commonly stated as "If you    have  four  groups  working  on  a  compiler,  you'll  get  a  4-pass    compiler".  The  original  statement was more general, "Organizations    which  design  systems  are  constrained to produce designs which are    copies  of the communication structures of these organizations." This    first  appeared  in  the  April  1968  issue of {Datamation}. Compare    {SNAFU principle}.
>
> The  law  was  named  after  Melvin Conway, an early proto-hacker who    wrote  an  assembler  for  the  Burroughs  220 called SAVE. (**The name    `SAVE'  didn't  stand  for  anything; it was just that you lost fewer    card  decks  and listings because they all had SAVE written on them.**)    There  is  also Tom Cheatham's amendment of Conway's Law: "If a group of N  persons implements a COBOL compiler, there will be N-1 passes. Someone in the group has to be the manager."

So, possibly the term save was chosen because it was *possibly* already used for the punch cards to separate the ones that need to be stored, kept, preserved...

Comment: I started as a programmer using punched cards. We didn't talk about *saving* them - we just *kept* them. And I don't remember writing either SAVE or KEEP on any given deck. But we often used to write our initials on particular cards to dissuade other programmers from pinching the more re-usable ones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Burroughs 220 is from late 50s. As Barrie reports OED says that 'save' was used since 1961 in the computer sense. Assuming you used punched cards in later years, after the term was established, I would say that the fact that you did not use this terminology does not substract much from the likelyhood (which is not high anyway) that the above lore is relevant.

Comment: I don't doubt that some sites used the word "save" much earlier than me, though I kinda doubt those "protected" decks were a factor. I'm just saying it wasn't necessarily widespread terminology, and it certainly wasn't used in the couple of places I used card decks in the early 70s.

Comment: Unreason, FumbleFingers: 'Save' for writing to disk was used at least as early as [1971](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/41048) at MIT (and in [1968](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6163) possibly for tape). Save was already used to refer to saving variables or information in a list in memory. I couldn't find any references relating save to punched cards.

Answer (score 5):

Saving is different from preserving or keeping in computer science; data that has not been saved has not been *written to persistent memory*. In reality this is a **writing operation** but "save" has been used to express the meaning to a less technical crowd. Save means to write the file to your computer in a way that will persist; "keeping" the data where it is before the save operation is actually not saving or writing the data.

You are not keeping or preserving because the data exists only in volatile memory, you can keep or preserve it in volatile memory but it is not written to a permanent location. You could think of the data as being saved from being lost when the volatile memory is lost, which happens each time the computer shuts down .

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/save) has a helpful Computer Science related definition of Save:

> 1. Computer Science To copy (a file) from a computer's main memory to a storage medium.

Comment: +1: data can be "written" to many places in the computer world. Not all of them will survive a loss of power (whether accidental or purposeful). To "save" is to write the data to a persistent digital storage mechanism, which does not depend on the computer running or even having power to maintain the copy. To "print" is to write the data in some human-readable text or graphical form, either on a computer monitor or (more commonly) paper.

Answer (score 2):

The OED’s first citation for the use of *save* in this sense is from 1961. There are several earlier uses of the verb which could have influenced the choice. They include:

> To keep, protect or guard (a thing) from damage, loss, or destruction.
>
> To keep intact or unhurt, preserve, maintain, safeguard (honour,
>   credit, chastity, and the like).
>
> To store, preserve, keep in sound condition.

Comment: though in 80's it really hit the mainstream: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=save+the+file%2Ckeep+the+file%2Cpreserve+the+file%2Cstore+the+file&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @Unreason The rise of the PC and floppy.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the others have pointed out, "save" does indeed mean to store it to persistent disk memory.  However, that still doesn't explain why someone chose the word "save" for that activity, as opposed to "keep", "store", "preserve" or "persist".

While I cannot find any evidence as to the *actual* origin, I would put out the possibility that "save" was selected simply because it sounded cooler :)

It may sound flippant, but I'm being entirely serious.  Engineers in my experience are fond of making word choices for purely aesthetic reasons, and "save" was coined long before the days when User Experience  design and natural domain language came into vogue.

Also consider some of the variant forms, like "autosave" and "unsaved". Autokeep?  Unpreserved?  They would work just as well grammatically, but they don't exactly roll off the tongue.